# Enable mini UART on CM3

Tags: uart, compute-module-3

I wan't to enable the mini UART on a CM3 for Linux console access in emergency cases.
The full UART will be used for other purposes.

With a newly flashed CM3 I can access the Linux console using GPIO14/15.
On the system this is `/dev/ttyAMA0`.

I have done the following steps:

1. [Disabled the system service](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md): `systemctl disable hciuart`
2. Edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` by removing `console=/dev/ttyAMA0,115200`
   The plan is to later add `console=/dev/ttyS0,115200`
3. Add these lines to `/boot/config.txt`

   dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
   enable_uart=1
   core_freq=250
4. Reboot

After the reboot I connect using ssh.
Inside I can't find `/dev/ttyS0`

Is the mini UART a viable option for emergency access to the Linux console?

What can I do to enable the mini UART?

What GPIO/pins will each UART appear on?
GPIO14/15 vs GPIO32/33

Answer (score 1):

At step 3 it was enough to add the following line.

```
dtoverlay=uart1,txd1_pin=32,rxd1_pin=33
```